# Why are some posts marked as highly active and others are not?

Tags: support, questions, question-protection

I came across a question while I was browsing the main section of Arqade which was classified as a highly active question: [Why are pokemon stacked on top of each other whenever I start?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/290449/why-are-pok%C3%A9mon-stacked-on-top-of-each-other-whenever-i-start)

I am a little confused as to why this is a highly active question when it only has one answer, was asked 4 years ago, and seemingly has had no action (besides the fact that it is active today) since 2016. A similar question with even more views and answers, although it is a little older, is not classified as an highly active question: [What is the optimal grid?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/229630/what-is-the-optimal-grid-size)

So why is the first one a highly active question while the second one is not? And why are some questions, seemingly randomly marked as 'highly active' while others, which have even more views and answers, are not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Highly active question" is a fairly new wording for [protected questions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/protect-questions). In general, questions are protected if they receive a high number of low quality answers.

In this particular case, the Pokemon Go question was [automatically protected by Community](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/290449/timeline#history_2470a0da-76e6-45df-8ae5-5ea2fda949b6) after a third answer was deleted. The Cities Skylines question has no deleted answers.

Comment: Thank you. I did not know that questions could be protected due to a large amount of deleted answers, but it does make sense in hindsight.

Answer (score -1):

I'd guess that it either:

- Is because of the upvotes
- I can't see, but may have a lot of deleted answer such as non-answers, vandalism, etc. (people just come and post the stupidest garbage for seemingly no reason it's really weird)